# LaTeX internal references for files and URLs

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a document with nearly 100 open source files that are referenced repeatedly throughout. Also, with each file is a URL, download URL, MD5 hash, etc.

Is there a quick and simple way to create an external file (say .ent) containing all this information and then reference each item within the publishable file (or the .tex)? That way, whenever a file is updated, I need only change the single entry in the static file and all references to that file throughout my document are also updated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have heard of applications of `biblatex` for other things than bibliography. Maybe this might a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you probably know `biblatex` only as a tool to create bibliographies, it is a powerful tool which can be used for a lot of things:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{database.ent}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{database.ent}
    @file{test,
        usera = {www.URL.com},
        userb = {www.downloadURL.com},
        userc = "md5123456"
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeurl}
{}
{\printfield{usera}}
{}
{}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citedownload}
{}
{\printfield{userb}}
{}
{}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citemd}
{}
{\printfield{userc}}
{}
{}

\begin{document}

\citeurl{test}

\citedownload{test}

\citemd{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In case you do not want to remember which field `usera` etc was supposed to be, you can create your own fields:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{database.ent}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{database.ent}
    @file{test,
        md = "md5123456"
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.dbx}
    \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{md}
    \DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{md}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citemd}
{}
{\printfield{md}}
{}
{}

\begin{document}

\citemd{test}

\end{document}
```

[The important thing here is, that the `\DeclareDatamodel` things cannot be in your current tex file, but have to be in an external file, `test.dbx` in this example]

Comment: samcarter, I think your answer best meets my needs. I am going to try and use your example and see if I can shoehorn it into my settings. I think this will work. I did not even think of trying biblatex as a possible solution.

Comment: @KerryCox Good luck! Maybe start with the first example, custom fields, like in the second example, can be tricky.

Comment: @KerryCox So did it work for your project?

Comment: No, it did not. I tried your first example and got only a test, test, test back. I am still new to LaTeX and have yet to try out the biblatex option. I'm just trying to finish up my book and when done, I'll try substituting and saving the variables. I did find the following link that looks promising as well: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37094/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-assign-a-value-to-a-variable-and-retrieve-it-for

Comment: @KerryCox Maybe a stupid question, but if you get test, test, test, did you run `(pdf)latex -> biber -> (pdf)latex -> (pdf)latex`? And does `biber` give you any errors or warnings?