# Is it possible to have a sequence (l3seq) as value in a property list (l3prop)?

Tags: expl3, l3prop, l3seq

This is quite related to [expl3: Is it possible to have a property list (l3prop) as value in a property list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325567/expl3-is-it-possible-to-have-a-property-list-l3prop-as-value-in-a-property-li)

Instead I want to have something like

```
\pushmetadata{author}{author1}
\pushmetadata{author}{author2}
\pushmetadata{title}{title1}
\pushmetadata{title}{title2}
...
```

and

```
\getmetadata{author}{1}
```

to get back the value in the sequence.

And meanwhile a way iterating/getting some sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to put `seq` in `prop`, but due to the nature of `expl3` containers, if one takes the sequence out from the property list and modify it, the changes will not reflect on the original sequence stored in the property list. It is still possible, however, to overwrite the entire sequence in the property list with an updated version. But one can imagine that there is huge overhead.

A clever design is to use **command names** as a "property list", where LaTeX does the key-val association for you. An example is shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set:Npn \__get_seq_name:n #1 {
  g__meta_#1_seq
}

\newcommand{\pushmetadata}[2]{
  \seq_if_exist:cF {\__get_seq_name:n {#1}} {
    \seq_new:c {\__get_seq_name:n {#1}}   
  }
  \seq_gput_right:cn {\__get_seq_name:n {#1}} {#2}
}

\newcommand{\getmetadata}[2]{
  \seq_item:cn {\__get_seq_name:n {#1}} {#2}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\pushmetadata{author}{John Doe}
\pushmetadata{author}{Doe Jane}
\pushmetadata{title}{title1}
\pushmetadata{title}{title2}

\par\getmetadata{author}{1}
\par\getmetadata{author}{2}
\par\getmetadata{title}{1}
\par\getmetadata{title}{2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is clever! Thank you.