# Detecting empty PGFKEYS

Tags: pgfkeys

I came across "[What is the recommended way to assign a value to a variable and retrieve it for later use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37094/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-assign-a-value-to-a-variable-and-retrieve-it-for)" while trying to figure out how to use PGFKEYS.  I'm having trouble, however, figuring out how to make it detect keys that are not set.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newcommand{\setValue}[1]{\pgfkeys{/variables/#1}}
\newcommand{\getValue}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/variables/#1}}
\newcommand{\declare}[1]{%
 \pgfkeys{
  /variables/#1.is family,
  /variables/#1.unknown/.style = {\pgfkeyscurrentpath/\pgfkeyscurrentname/.initial = ##1}
 }%
}

\declare{}

\newcommand{\leftTailA}[1]{%
  \declare{@mLT/} 
  \setValue{@mLT, Label = #1 } 
  \ifx\getValue{@mLT/Label}\empty
  \else
    $>$\getValue{@mLT/Label}$<$
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\leftTailB}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\empty
  \else
    $>$#1$<$
  \fi
}

\pgfkeys{
  /distMarkup/.is family, /distMarkup,
  default/.style = { leftTailLabel = {} },
  leftTailLabel/.estore in = \myLeftTailLabel,
}

\newcommand\distMarkup[1][]{% Note, don't put a space between the , and the #1, why? I don't know.
  \pgfkeys{/distMarkup, default,#1}
  \ifx\myLeftTailLabel\empty
  \else 
    $>$\myLeftTailLabel$<$
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

A: This has a label: \leftTailA{ label number 1 }

A: This has no label: \leftTailA{}

B: This has a label: \leftTailB{ label number 1 }

B: This has no label: \leftTailB{}

MA: This has a label: \distMarkup[leftTailLabel=label number 1]

MA: This has no label: \distMarkup[]

\end{document}
```

The output from this code sample is:

> A: This has a label: > label number 1<
>
> A: This has no label: ><
>
> B: This has a label: > label number 1 <
>
> B: This has no label:
>
> MA: This has a label: >label number 1<
>
> MA: This has no label:

**In particular, I don't understand why "A: This has no label" says "><" rather than nothing.**

Extra Credit:  What does the ##1 do in the \declare declaration?

Comment: Also, you say "% Note, don't put a space between the , and the #1, why? I don't know." It absolutely does not matter whether or not you put a space there.

Comment: I've posted a separate question/MWE that shows that pdflatex is sensitive to this space.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523567/why-does-the-space-in-pgfkeys-matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem I identify looking at your code is line `\ifx\getValue{@mLT/Label}\empty`. The behavior of `\ifx` is to compare the two tokens immediately following `\ifx` and check if they are the same. In this case those two tokens are `\getValue` and `{`. These two tokens are never the same, so the false branch is always taken.

The fix is to use `\pgfkeysgetvalue` to store the value into a macro and then do the comparison:

```
\newcommand{\leftTailA}[1]{%
  \declare{@mLT/}%
  \setValue{@mLT, Label = #1 }%
  \pgfkeysgetvalue{@mLT/Label}{\temp}
  \ifx\getValue\temp\empty
  \else
    $>$\getValue{@mLT/Label}$<$%
  \fi
}
```

Similarly the comparison in `\leftTailB` is wrong. A fix would be to store the argument of `\leftTailB` into a macro and then compare that macro to `\empty` with `\ifx` as in:

```
\newcommand{\leftTailB}[1]{%
  \def\temp{#1}%
  \ifx\temp\empty
  \else
    $>$#1$<$%
  \fi
}
```

If you are doing many comparisons, you could define a command called `\ifempty`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ifempty#1{%
    \def\temp{#1}%
    \ifx\temp\empty
       \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
       \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}

\def\ifpgfkeyempty#1{%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{#1}{\temp}%
    \ifx\temp\empty
       \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
       \ifx\temp\relax
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo
       \else
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
       \fi
    \fi
}
\makeatother
```

The `##1` in `\declare` is the argument to the undefined key. You define an undefined key handler that makes any undefined key into a new key and stores the value passed into it. If you said directly:

```
/variables/.unknown/.style = {\pgfkeyscurrentpath/\pgfkeyscurrentname/.initial = #1}
```

then `\pgfkeys{/variables/some new key=some value}` makes `some new key` into a new variable key and stores `some value` into it. Inside of a macro, `#1` refers to the first argument of the macro. The doubled `##` is used to escape `#1` so that it refers to the argument of the undefined key rather than to the argument of `\declare`.

To indicate the relationship between `#1` and `##1`, consider the code:

```
 \def\test#1{\def\testinner##1{(#1/##1)}}
 \test{a} % This defines \testinner as #1->(a/#1)
 \testinner{b} % expands to (a/b)
```

Full code (by the way this is still not good code):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newcommand{\setValue}[1]{\pgfkeys{/variables/#1}}
\newcommand{\getValue}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/variables/#1}}
\newcommand{\declare}[1]{%
 \pgfkeys{
  /variables/#1.is family,
  /variables/#1.unknown/.style = {\pgfkeyscurrentpath/\pgfkeyscurrentname/.initial = ##1}
 }%
}

\declare{}

\makeatletter
\def\ifempty#1{%
    \def\temp{#1}%
    \ifx\temp\empty
       \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
       \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}

\def\ifpgfkeyempty#1{%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{#1}{\temp}%
    \ifx\temp\empty
       \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
       \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\leftTailA}[1]{%
  \declare{@mLT/}%
  \setValue{@mLT/Label = #1 }%
  \ifpgfkeyempty{/variables/@mLT/Label}{}{%
      $>$\getValue{@mLT/Label}$<$%
  }
}

\newcommand{\leftTailB}[1]{%
  \ifempty{#1}{}{%
    $>$#1$<$%
  }
}

\pgfkeys{
  /distMarkup/.is family, /distMarkup,
  default/.style = { leftTailLabel = {} },
  leftTailLabel/.estore in = \myLeftTailLabel,
}

\newcommand\distMarkup[1][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/distMarkup, default,#1}%
  \ifx\myLeftTailLabel\empty
  \else
    $>$\myLeftTailLabel$<$%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

A: This has a label: \leftTailA{ label number 1 }

A: This has no label: \leftTailA{}

B: This has a label: \leftTailB{ label number 1 }

B: This has no label: \leftTailB{}

MA: This has a label: \distMarkup[leftTailLabel=label number 1]

MA: This has no label: \distMarkup[]

\end{document}
```

Comment: if the \ifx is not the right comparison to use, then I'm fine with replacing it.  The solution you propose has the same issue that the other answer has in that I have to add extra code for each comparison I want to do.  Is there a replacement for the \ifx or for how the initialization is done?  This would simplify things because I have many such instances I need to address.

Comment: @ChristopherDonham We need more information. Can you say what you are actually trying to do? You can easily define a new command called `\ifempty`.

Comment: The MWE is farily representative of the use case.  The actual situation is that I am using TIKZ to illustrate hypothesis tests for the class I teach on statistics.  For different hypothesis tests, I need to print or not print test statistics, alpha values, problem values, probabilities, means, etc.  The way I control whether each is printed is by whether or not the value is defined in calls to a command.  There are two such commands, one that passes by location (e.g. a typical latex command) and more recently I've been experimenting with passing by name.  Writing an \ifempty would be fine.

Comment: I added an `\ifempty` and a `\ifpgfkeyempty`. You might want to add handling for the case that the pgf key is undefined to `\ifpgfkeyempty`. If it's undefined, maybe it should count as empty?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  I will see if I can duplicate the case where that space in the code mattered, and if so, post it as a separate question.

Comment: If you have a moment, could you post as a comment an example line that shows how to use the ##1 code?

Comment: @ChristopherDonham I added a basic example showing the use of `##1`.

Comment: Thanks.  My comment should have been more clear.  I understand the usage case that you demonstrate where the ##1 is used with \def.  What I'm not understanding is how the ##1 is used to do something useful in the context of the pgfkeys and declare code that I swiped from another source.  Is the ##1 what allows the setvalue to assign a value to a variable?

Comment: `##1` is the argument to the unknown key. If you say `/declared family/unknown key = value` then `value` goes into `##1`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\newcommand{\setValue}[1]{\pgfkeys{/variables/#1}}
\newcommand{\getValue}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/variables/#1}}
\newcommand{\declare}[1]{%
 \pgfkeys{
  /variables/#1.is family,
  /variables/#1.unknown/.style = {\pgfkeyscurrentpath/\pgfkeyscurrentname/.initial = ##1}
 }%
}

\declare{}

\newcommand{\leftTailA}[1]{%
  \declare{@mLT/}% 
  \setValue{@mLT, Label = #1 }%
  \edef\tmp{\getValue{@mLT/Label}}%
  \ifx\tmp\empty
  \else
    $>$\getValue{@mLT/Label}$<$%
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\leftTailB}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\empty
  \else
    $>$#1$<$%
  \fi
}

\pgfkeys{
  /distMarkup/.is family, /distMarkup,
  default/.style = { leftTailLabel = {} },
  leftTailLabel/.estore in = \myLeftTailLabel,
}

\newcommand\distMarkup[1][]{% Note, don't put a space between the , and the #1, why? I don't know.
  \pgfkeys{/distMarkup, default,#1}%
  \ifx\myLeftTailLabel\empty
  \else 
    $>$\myLeftTailLabel$<$%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

A: This has a label: \leftTailA{ label number 1 }

A: This has no label: \leftTailA{}

B: This has a label: \leftTailB{ label number 1 }

B: This has no label: \leftTailB{}

MA: This has a label: \distMarkup[leftTailLabel=label number 1]

MA: This has no label: \distMarkup[]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is what I am looking for, but it has the problem that I have to add a separate line for each value that I want to test.  My MWE has only one value, but my actual code has many such values.  Is there a way to put it into the \ifx statement?  I was also wondering if my problem has to do with the ##1 code.

Comment: @ChristopherDonham Yes, the problem is the `\ifx`. The other answer uses the same method as mine but uses `\pgfkeysgetvalue{/variables/@mLT/Label}{\temp}`, which also stores the value in a macro for the `\ifx` comparison. The problem is not the `##1` code. It is a well know fact that `\ifx` does not always compare the things you wanted it to compare.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fully expandable solution. `\pgfkeysvalueof` must be expanded three times until one get the actual value of the key, so we need 2*3+1 `\expandafter`s.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter

\def\pgfkeys@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\def\pgfkeys@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}

\def\ifpgfkeysempty#1{%
  \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\pgfkeysvalueof{#1}}\relax
    \expandafter\pgfkeys@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\pgfkeys@secondoftwo
  \fi}

\def\pgfkeysmeaning#1{%
  {\ttfamily #1->|\detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\pgfkeysvalueof{#1}}|}}

\makeatother

\pgfkeys{%
  /test1/.initial = {},
  /test2/.initial = \relax,
  /test3/.initial = {Foo},
  /test4/.initial = {\def#1\bar{bar}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \pgfkeysmeaning{/test1}

  \ifpgfkeysempty{/test1}{Key is empty}{Key is not empty}
\item \pgfkeysmeaning{/test2}

  \ifpgfkeysempty{/test2}{Key is empty}{Key is not empty}
\item \pgfkeysmeaning{/test3}

  \ifpgfkeysempty{/test3}{Key is empty}{Key is not empty}
\item \pgfkeysmeaning{/test4}

  \ifpgfkeysempty{/test4}{Key is empty}{Key is not empty}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]